# Getting node error EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, build, reactstrap

I have a react app I used react create app when running "npm start" it works just fine but when running "npm run build" I get this error

```
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\Public\me\work\Luca\frontenduser\dist\C:\Users\Public\me\work\Luca\frontenduser\node_modules\reactstrap\es'
```

node : 12.18.3
reactstrap : 8.5.1
Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use WIN+R to open a small window of operation, and then enter '.' (dot) And click OK, so that you enter the system user directory of your C drive;

After entering the system user directory, you can find the file .npmrc This file, after opening this file, you can see the [prefix value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IPZr.png)

now change whatever the prefix=xxxx value is. with the given image. And now try again.

This solved my problem.
or lookup this link:
https://www.programmersought.com/article/91716179653/